fit tabs spacing on active tabs
I've issue with tabs spacing active tabs. Refer this image bellow for more clear

this my issue code as your reference..
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.09,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
                Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        indicator: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            color: Color(0xFF1480E0),
                        ),
                        labelColor: Colors.white,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                        tabs: [
                            Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                2,
                                child: Tab(
                                    text: 'tab 1',
                                ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                2,
                                child: Tab(
                                    text: 'tab 2',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                    0.43,
                    child: TabBarView(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        children: [
                            Center(
                                child: Text(
                                    'Content 1',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            Center(
                                child: Text(
                                    'Content 2',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    );
}


Set isScrollable to false: By default, TabBar tries to fit all tabs within its width.
TabBar(
controller: _tabController,
isScrollable: false,
labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
// ... other properties
)

You should set labelPadding to zero like this:

Result:

